# Migrating a view in sql server changes it to a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, migrate

When I migrate a view from sql server to sql on a different server using the copy data wizard, it changes it to a table.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script out the view as a CREATE statement, and simply run that on the other server.

Comment: No wizard to move the tables and views all at once?